# PostgresSQL extract a word from sentence that has a special character in it

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have sentence field in my table which is similar to this

```
id    text
100   the quick %brown fox %jumped over the %lazy dog
101   how are %you? Nice to %meet you
```

I want to extract only the words that have the % appended to them so my output would be

```
%brown
%jumped
%lazy
%you
%meet
```

So I tried using the regexp_split_to_array but failed miserably.
My table is in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what exactly did not work for you with regexp? eg:

```
t=# select regexp_matches('the quick %brown fox %jumped over the %lazy dog','%[a-z]{1,}','g');
 regexp_matches
----------------
 {%brown}
 {%jumped}
 {%lazy}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: That was quick! I was trying regexp_matches(text, '^*(%)*$', 'ig') but I think I dont have the fundamental understand of how regex works. If its possible, can you explain what you have done here?

Comment: the mask? % and any alphabet at least once